# Is it possible to modify an MS Access database schema using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, ado.net, dao

I need to modify the *schema* of an MS Acess database (.mdb) via code.

Since the Jet Engine DDL statements (ALTER TABLE, etc.) are quite poorly documented, I'd prefer to use some kind of object library like DAO (`myDatabase.TableDefs("myTable").Fields.Append(myNewField)`) or ADOX (`myCatalog.Tables("myTable").Columns.Append(myNewField)`) or SMO (which is only available for SQL Server, syntax similar - you get the idea).

Is there something similar like ADOX for ADO.NET or am I stuck with using DDL statements or referencing the old DAO/ADOX libraries?

Comment: What do you mean it is [poorly documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267262%28v=office.12%29.aspx)? Which statement is not clear to you? Anyway, you can use ADOX in .NET. For example, see [How to create an Access database by using ADOX and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317881).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks like the documentation has been vastly improved in the latest versions of Access. Still, one example: The ALTER TABLE page does not contain a list of valid data types; it is completely unclear (from the documentation), for example, how I would create a new decimal with precision X and scale Y. In the meantime, I've found such a table of data type keywords (it's linked in the user comments section of the [CREATE TABLE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177893.aspx)), but that's far from the quality of, for example, the SQL Server BOL.

Comment: Don't know of an ADOX "update" for .NET. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317881) is an example of ADOX with C# to create a database, however. And, yes, the DDL for Access IS very poorly documented, but there are books that can help.

Comment: Oh, and another reason why managing Access schemas via DDL is not a good idea: [The schema rowsets are broken.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/58a17c99-0b23-4341-a274-db2dd91e0886) I've just learned the hard way that neither OLE DB schema tables nor ODBC schema tables return the correct IS_NULLABLE values for Access fields. It seems like the *only* reliable way to check whether an Access field is nullable is to use **DAO** and check for `myField.Required`. How pathetic is that? Having to add a DAO reference to a .net project in 2012...

Comment: It has been my experience as far back as .NET 1.0 Beta that DAO via COM interop is the best for what you are trying to do...or switch to SQLite if you can :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had decent success with straight ddl statements. Your right the syntax requires a smidge of googling to tease out but I have been handling updates to a local db this way for a while.  Is there a specific update you are having issues with?
Basically I wrote a few helper functions to check the structure of a table and append fields if needed.

```
public bool doesFieldExist(string table, string field)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        try
        {
            if (!openRouteCon())
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not open Route DB");
            }
            DataTable tb = new DataTable();
            string sql = "select top 1 * from " + table;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, routedbcon);
            da.Fill(tb);
            if (tb.Columns.IndexOf(field) > -1)
            {
                ret = true;
            }

            tb.Dispose();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Debug("Check for field:" + table + "." + field + ex.Message);
        }

        return ret;
    }


    public bool checkAndAddColumn(string t, string f, string typ, string def = null)
    {

        // Update RouteMeta if needed.
        if (!doesFieldExist(t, f))
        {
            string sql;
            if (def == null)
            {
                sql = String.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD COLUMN {1} {2} ", t, f, typ);
            }
            else
            {
                sql = String.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD COLUMN {1} {2} DEFAULT {3} ", t, f, typ, def);
            }
            try
            {
                if (openRouteCon())
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, routedbcon);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string msg = "Modified :" + t + " added col " + f;
                    log.Info(msg);
                    if (def != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("update {0} set {1} = {2}", t, f, def);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            log.Error("Could not update column to new default" + t + "-" + f + "-" + e.Message);
                        }

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Could not alter RouteDB:" + t + " adding col " + f + "-" + ex.Message);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```